# Multiple "properties" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, properties

Just a fast and simple question: how do I add multiple classes to the same element? I got this code and I want to be able to apply `class1`, `class2`, `class3` to this function. The markerClasses are different marks on a map and I want to be able to choose which mark I want to use on my page (`class1`, `class2`...).

```
$(function(){
  $('.map').mobilymap({
    markerClass: 'class1'
  });
});
```

I thought it would be something like `markerClass: 'class1 class2'` or `markerClass: '.class1 .class2'` but it won't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends.  What's `mobilymap`?

Comment: @SLaks It's a plugin I'm using, http://playground.mobily.pl/jquery/mobily-map/demo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module seems to not support multiple classes by default, but the current version should work if you do something like that:

```
$(function(){
    $('.map').mobilymap({
        markerClass: 'class1, .class2, .class3'
    });
});
```

(I know, it looks strange, but the module was not developed to support that at the moment)

Please test it and tell me if it worked correctly. It should treat all the elements with classes `class1`, `class2` and `class3` equally, as if they have one class specified by `markerClass` setting.

Comment: Never mind, it worked perfectly! Realized I missed a dot in your example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't mind this plugin limitations and add your owns classes **after** your mobilymap thingy:

```
$(function(){
  $('.map').mobilymap({
    markerClass: 'marker'
  });
  $('.marker').addClass('class1 class2 class3');
});
```

Comment: Arnaud, you have added dot to the name of the class and module needs the name of the class, not the whole class selector, because it adds dot anyway (so `marker` instead of `.marker` is needed).

Comment: Exact! @Cheezen: try the new one ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because they aren't actually setting the class in their code. They are also only looking for a single class.

```
point = $this.find("." + sets.markerClass)
```

and here

```
div = content.find("." + sets.markerClass).filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr("id") == rel
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Then I get it but I don't know how to make it look for multiple classes.